# Installing pygame problem "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required"

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to install pygame but i get this error:

distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

```
Collecting pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/a0/63f9ca836e6a08e560f1ef3f2535ffb46bfdad2abb093dd097dae252be28/pygame-2.0.0.dev6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...

Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.10-VC.zip 0bbac0106358dc99b8ba2401ae6a1c10d3927ca9
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.10-VC.zip:
Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.14-VC.zip c64d90c1f7d1bb3f3dcfcc255074611f017cdcc4
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.14-VC.zip:
Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip 9097148f4529cf19f805ccd007618dec280f0ecc
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip:
Downloading... https://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsr9c.zip 9ca086c960ffc4bff821ba194c8d0a15f69eae09
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\jpegsr9c.zip:
Downloading... https://bitbucket.org/llindstrom/pygame/downloads/prebuilt-x86-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip dbce1d5ea27b3da17273e047826d172e1c34b478
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\prebuilt-x86-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip:
copying into .\prebuilt-x86
Path for SDL: prebuilt-x86\SDL2-2.0.10
...Library directory for SDL: prebuilt-x86/SDL2-2.0.10/lib/x86
...Include directory for SDL: prebuilt-x86/SDL2-2.0.10/include
Path for FONT: prebuilt-x86\SDL2_ttf-2.0.14
...Library directory for FONT: prebuilt-x86/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14/lib/x86
...Include directory for FONT: prebuilt-x86/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14/include
Path for IMAGE: prebuilt-x86\SDL2_image-2.0.5
...Library directory for IMAGE: prebuilt-x86/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x86
...Include directory for IMAGE: prebuilt-x86/SDL2_image-2.0.5/include
Path for MIXER: prebuilt-x86\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4
...Library directory for MIXER: prebuilt-x86/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/lib/x86
...Include directory for MIXER: prebuilt-x86/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/include
Path for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x86
...Library directory for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x86/lib
...Include directory for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x86/include
DLL for SDL2: prebuilt-x86/SDL2-2.0.10/lib/x86/SDL2.dll
DLL for SDL2_ttf: prebuilt-x86/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14/lib/x86/SDL2_ttf.dll
DLL for SDL2_image: prebuilt-x86/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x86/SDL2_image.dll
DLL for SDL2_mixer: prebuilt-x86/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/lib/x86/SDL2_mixer.dll
DLL for portmidi: prebuilt-x86/lib/portmidi.dll
Path for FREETYPE not found.
...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x86.
Path for PNG not found.
...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x86.
Path for JPEG not found.
...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x86.
DLL for freetype: prebuilt-x86/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14/lib/x86/libfreetype-6.dll

---
For help with compilation see:
    https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
To contribute to pygame development see:
    https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py", line 258, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 208, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 574, in main
    return setup_prebuilt_sdl2(prebuilt_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 499, in setup_prebuilt_sdl2
    DEPS.configure()
  File "C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 336, in configure
    from . import vstools
  File "C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\vstools.py", line 11, in <module>
    compiler.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 372, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Operator\PycharmProjects\Spaceinvader\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 147, in msvc9_query_vcvarsall
  File "C:\Users\Operator\PycharmProjects\Spaceinvader\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1227, in return_env
  File "C:\Users\Operator\PycharmProjects\Spaceinvader\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 876, in VCIncludes
  File "C:\Users\Operator\PycharmProjects\Spaceinvader\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 555, in VCInstallDir
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\
```

pip is updated, setuptools updated

I've just installed Visual Studio and Visual Studio Build Tolls 2019 but still get this error.

I dont really know what i can do now

Maybe it must be exactly 14.1 version ?

Comment: It sounds like Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required.

Comment: but i can't find 14.1 version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I noticed this error might be as a result of either wrong python path on the system environment variables or you have defined more than one python environment on your project. Also having multiple versions of Python. To solve this problem, you can reinstall Python. However, this is not a guarantee solution, but checking your project interpreter and the Python environment should be a good place to begin.
On the project interpreter click the plus sign to set up a new environment for your project.
Option 2: check out this link https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html to create a new python environment for your project. But make sure you only have one version of python installed. This worked well for me.
[image]